# DITA sequence collection

Tags: xml, sequence, dita, topic-maps

I want to get a webhelp output of a DITA map with a sequence collection type of topics that does not correspond to the sequence of those topics in the map. In fact, some of these topics nest subtopics which have an unordered relationship among each other, which is why I want to show the main flow/steps of tasks/issues only without those distracting subtopics. They should just be skipped in the sequence, however visible in the TOC.
I have read that ***reltable*** is the solution, but it does not work.

```
<relcell>
    <topicref href="tasks/t_work_steps_annotation.xml" type="task"/>
</relcell>
<relcell>
    <topicgroup collection-type="sequence">
        <topicref href="tasks/t_delivery.xml" type="task" scope="local"/>
        <topicref href="tasks/t_initialAnalysis.xml" type="task" scope="local"/>
        <topicref href="concepts/c_entityCognition.xml" type="concept" scope="local"/>
        <topicref href="tasks/t_counterCheckContent.xml" type="task" scope="local"/>
        <topicref href="references/r_AnnotationOutput.xml" type="reference" scope="local"/>

    </topicgroup>
</relcell>
```

My approach looks like this (detail of ***reltable*** see above), but it yields a family-type collection instead of a sequence-type. I use oXygen for conversion, output is HTML-WebHelp. Can anyone locate the mistake?

Kind regards,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

I looked in the DITA 1.2 specs but it does not seem to indicate that you can overwrite the collection-type defined in the DITA Map from a relationship table. And indeed it does not work. 
I did not try but maybe you could find a CSS-based solution, mark certain topic root elements with an @outputclass attribute and try to have a custom CSS which may be able to match the related-links div and add some counters to the sub-links.

Comment: Indeed the DITA map has no collection-type specification at all, it is arranged as follows <topicref href="tasks/t_delivery.xml" type="task"></topicref>
   <topicref href="tasks/t_initialAnalysis.xml" type="task">
    <topicref href="tasks/t_createAbstract.xml" ></topicref>
    <topicref href="tasks/t_rephraseTitle.xml" type="task"></topicref>
   </topicref>
   <topicref href="concepts/c_entityCognition.xml" type="concept" scope="local">

Comment: Clearer Layout:
Indeed the DITA map has no collection-type specification at all, it is arranged as follows
    <topicref href="tasks/t_delivery.xml" type="task"></topicref>
    <topicref href="tasks/t_initialAnalysis.xml" type="task">
         ....(subtasks that should not go into the sequence)
    </topicref>
    <topicref href="concepts/c_entityCognition.xml" type="concept" scope="local"> 
just to show the first three topics.